# Bind a jQuery plugin function to many elements in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to attach a plugin function to multiple elements on a page.

For a single element, the function is attached like this (`limiter` being the plugin function):

```
if (fullDescription.length) {
    fullDescription.limiter(1000, fullDescriptionCounter);
}
```

I need to attach this plugin to multiple elements on a page. To achieve it, I came up with this code:

```
if (categoryDescription.length) {
    $.each(categoryDescription, function(index, value) {
        value.limiter(180, categoryDescriptionCounter);
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, `limiter` is not accessible from within the anonymous function that is a callback to the `$.each()`  iterator.

What are my options to get the job done? How can I bind `limiter` to the anonymous function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this`:

```
$.each(categoryDescription, function(index, value) {
    $(this).limiter(180, categoryDescriptionCounter);
});
```

please note that any well-written plugin should already handle multiple instances:

e.g.

```
 categoryDescription.limiter(180, categoryDescriptionCounter);
```

Also note: The check for the length should also not be not needed for any self-respecting plugin. jQuery objects allow for running methods on zero-length collections. They just do nothing :)

Comment: thank you for a neat solution. There is also this `categoryDescriptionCounter` which in my code is a set of elements. On each iteration I want to pass only the current element. This does not seem to work: `$(this).limiter(180, categoryDescriptionCounter[index]);`

Comment: @luqo33: You would need to provide a full example of the code for that as it goes beyond your original question. Maybe a new question with JSFiddle? :)

Comment: going back to your answer (which works perfectly). Why  is  `$(this).limiter()` not equivalent to `value.limiter()`  when `value` is an obejct value of each eleemnt in `categoryDescription` . Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Inside an each the "value" parameter is the same as "this", which is a DOM element too. You can wrap value as $(value) instead but I usually drop the parameter and go with $(this) just out of habit. Minification should mean $(value) can work out shorter as "this" is never minimised.

Answer (score 1):

Because value is a dom element reference not a jQuery wrapper object so it won't have access to jQuery plugin methods.

You could just call the plugin in the entire object set like below

```
if (categoryDescription.length) {
    categoryDescription.limiter(180, categoryDescriptionCounter);
}
```

If the plugin does not support being called on a set of elements loop through the set of elements like

```
if (categoryDescription.length) {
    categoryDescription.each(function (index, value) {
        $(value).limiter(180, categoryDescriptionCounter);
    });
}
```

Comment: A *length check* is a waste of time with jQuery objects. They are simple a zero-length collection that still have all the methods. They just do nothing :)